# Is that possible to change the color of icons used in app according to selected theme in app in objective c.(programmatically)

Tags: ios

I need to change the color of sliced icons used in app in different color. I dont want to take more and more images i.e. of different color. I want to change the color of image only, not other properties of image e.g. shape, size, layer, opacity etc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you construct your icons correctly, you can use the [Hue Adjust](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIHueAdjust) `CIFilter`. You'd just need to change the `inputAngle` to get the color you want. For example, if your icon is mostly blue, you can make a mostly yellow one by changing `inputAngle` to 180° (or π radians - not sure of the units).